# pyqt how to insertRecord in QSqlQueryModel /QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

update...

besides the situation mentioned before, now I wanna to fetch data online, and display data with tableview, save data at the same time.
Provided I adopt the `QSqlQueryModel` approach. everytime I get a new record from online, I need to `setQuery()` to refresh the tableView. If the records amount a lot, `setQuery()` will result in repainting over and over again, which will deteriorate the performance of GUI responsiveness.

so, any good idea to customize the subclassing of `QSqlQueryModel`

---

I want to read from two database tables which share some the same field and modify data back.
below is a minimum demo.
I fetch data from two tables with ```QSqlQuery```, and set model with  ```QSqlTableModel```. Data displaying is successful. But I don't know how to write data back. In the demo ```insertRecord()``` doesn't work.
It seems that the ```model``` object is not specified to a certain table. If I ```setTable()```, the tableView will display wrongly.

should I use `QSqlRelationalTableModel`?

And will the `QSqlQuery` be enough with `exec()` method and view and database will be synchronized at the same time?

database table test:

[image: table tast]

database table test2

[image]

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,QTableView, QVBoxLayout,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel,QSqlRecord

class demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(lyt)
        tview = QTableView()
        btn = QPushButton('add')
        lyt.addWidget(tview)
        lyt.addWidget(btn)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName(r"xxx.db")
        print(db.open())
        self.model = testModel(db)
        tview.setModel(self.model)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.insertNewRecord)
    
    def insertNewRecord(self):
        r = self.model.record()
        r.setValue('name', 'alex')
        r.setValue('age', 23)
        r.setValue('gender','male')
        if self.model.insertRecord(0, r):

            print(self.model.submitAll())
            print(self.model.lastError().text())
        else:
            self.model.db.rollback()
            print(self.model.lastError().text())
        self.model.select()
        
class testModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super().__init__()
        self.db = db
        self.setQuery(QSqlQuery('select a.name, a.age, b.gender from test as a inner join test2 as b on a.name=b.name'))
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        print(self.lastError().text())
        print(self.tableName())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = demo()
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

once excuted, print `True` correspond to `self.db.open()`, the other two `print(xxx)` return None

[image]

once I clicked the 'add' button, view changed, new row added, the command line returns error:

[image]

second time I clicked the 'add' button, view changed, new row added, the command line returns error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i don't understand... when you say you want to read from two tables do you mean database tables or do you mean tableview widget tables?.... please try to clarify your question and post any error messages or describe what it is doing that it shouldn't be.

Comment: Also, as already told you, you should do all database session related code **before** creating the model instance, including *opening*. Besides, your model has absolutely no use of explicit access to `self.db` (unless you need access to different databases, but even in that case, it should be part of the constructor), so you could just remove it from there.

Comment: @musicamante I've declared the db before declare model. Your method works for one database table. This time I fetch data from two table with QSqlQuery. I get the QRecord from the model. I 've checked the newly created record's field name, they are the selected fields in the ```QSqlQuery('xxxx')```. with the ```insertRecord()``` executed, record will be stored in two tables in the certain fields? However I got an error, not the "No fields to Update"

Comment: @Arthur please read more carefully: I also referred to the *opening*; besides, it doesn't make sense to open the db in the model instance (what if you create two instances of the model?). Also, as the `setQuery()` [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setQuery) explains: " You should normally not call it on a QSqlTableModel". If you want custom queries, then use QSqlQueryModel, if you just need filtering or sorting, set a QSortFilterProxyModel for the sql model.

Comment: @musicamante ok, I've modified the code. QSqlQueryModel is only for reading, but I want to insert rows and update record later. if not using ```setQuery()```, I cannot fetch data from two database tables

Comment: The class name is clear: QSqlTableModel is for a **database table**, but you want a model for a specific *query*, so you can't use it; I know that QSqlQueryModel is read-only, but as the documentation explains, "To make it read-write, you must subclass it and reimplement setData() and flags()".

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are trying to execute an insert on *a result set from a join* rather than an actual table. SQLite does not support updating multiple tables using a single insert statement. Each table must be updated independently. The `QSqlRelationalTableModel` class may make this possible, but if you don't need in-place editing, it may be easier to do everything yourself using `QSqlQuery`. Personally, I much prefer to define a view for displaying the data, and then use triggers for making updates - but that can be quite complicated to set up.

Comment: @ekhumoro if I subclass QSqlQueryModel, if there are any good method to apply changes in the view if database changes besides ```setQuery()```

Comment: Not really - the `QSqlTableModel` class has a [select method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html), but that doesn't do much more than call `setQuery()`. If you use `QSqlQueryModel` you must do everything using SQL statements, but that gets you a lot of flexibility. The other Qt Sql classes are only really suitable for quite simple use-cases.